# Return a dataframe from a function and store it in the workspace

Tags: r, return, dataframe, assign

This is my first week working with R and there is one thing about function I cannot seems to manage.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10),
             b = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "c", "c", "b"))

testF = function(select) {
dum = subset(df, b == select)
}

lapply(unique(df$b), testF)
```

This function now just prints the the data sets on screen. But I would like to store the results as separate data frames in my workspace. In this example this would give three data frames; a, b and c.

Thank for the help.

Comment: Write line 'dum' as the last line of the function and it should return the object from the function.

Comment: Read `help("function")`. You should also read `help("subset")`, which warns explicitly against using `subset` inside functions.

Comment: @Roland what is an example of one of those unanticipated consequences?

Comment: @rawr See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/1412059.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roland has the correct solution for the specific problem: more than a `split()` is not needed. Just to make sure: `split()` returns a list. To get separate data frames in you workspace, you do:

```
list2env(split(df,df$b),.GlobalEnv)
```

Or, using assign:

```
tmp <- split(df,df$b)
for(i in names(tmp)) assign(i,tmp[[i]])
```

---

**A word on subset**

This said, some more detail on why your function is plain wrong. First of all, in `?subset` you read:

> **Warning**
>
> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset
>   can have unanticipated consequences.

Translates to: Never ever in your life use `subset()` within a function again.

---

**A word on returning values from a function**

Next to that, a function always returns a result:

- if a `return()` statement is used, it returns whatever is given as an argument to `return()`.
- otherwise it returns the result of the last line.

In your case, the last line contains an assignment. Now an assignment also returns a value, but you don't see it. It's returned `invisibly`. You can see it by wrapping it in parentheses, for example:

```
> x <- 10
> (x <- 20)
[1] 20
```

This is absolutely unnecessary. It's the reason why your function works when used in `lapply()` (lapply catches invisible output), but won't give you any (visible) output when used at the command line. You can capture it though :

```
> testF("b")
> x <- testF("b")
> x
    a b
3   3 b
6   6 b
10 10 b
```

The assignment in your function doesn't make sense: either you return `dum` explicitly, or you just drop the assignment alltogether

---

**Correcting your function**

So, given this is just an example and the real problem wouldn't be solved by simply using `split()` your function would be :

```
testF <- function(select) {
    dum <- df[df$b=select,]
    return(dum)
}
```

or simply:

```
testF <- function(select){
    df[df$b=select,]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive and detailed reaction. And I just will never ever use the subset() again, even outside functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs a return value. See `help("function")` for details.

However, for your specific case you can simply use `split`:

```
split(df, df$b)

$a
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 a
7 7 a

$b
    a b
3   3 b
6   6 b
10 10 b

$c
  a b
4 4 c
5 5 c
8 8 c
9 9 c
```

Comment: Maybe it's interesting to point out that `split()` returns a list,  that you can use `assign()` to create separate data frames and that this is in general a bad idea. Creating different data frames when you can just work with a list, that is.

Comment: Or `list2env` if you have a list and for some strange reason "must" put its content into the global environment.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help. I will use split and work my way through the help pages.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `list2env` function described in the comment above, assuming you wish to use the `subset` method regardless of potential issues inside a function.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10),
             b = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "c", "c", "b"))

testF = function(select) {
    dum = subset(df, b == select)
    dum                                # you need to return the data frame resulting from the subset back out of the function
}

my.list = lapply(unique(df$b), testF)
names(my.list) = unique(df$b)          # set the names of the list elements to the subsets they represent (a,b,c)
list2env(my.list,envir = .GlobalEnv)   # copy the data frames from the list to the Global Environment
```

If you had a simple example like the one you portray you could access the elements of the list one-by-one as follows and assign each to a variable.

```
a = my.list[[1]]
b = my.list[[2]]
c = my.list[[3]]
```

Finally, you could define the function inline such and make use of the (awesome) `data.table` package, thereby avoiding the use of subset:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1:10),
             b = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a", "c", "c", "b"))   
my.list = lapply(unique(dt$b), function(select) { dt[b == eval(select)]})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As specifically pointed out in `?subset` you're NOT supposed to use subset within a function. subset is a convenience function. Use `df[df$b==select,]` to avoid huge trouble at some point.

Comment: Noted @Joris Meys, I've included an example at the bottom which avoids this.  Should my answer therefore remove the `subset` reference?  I'm not sure of good practice on answering these questions.  Also, I included a `data.table` example as opposed to `df[df$b==select,]` purely because I think the package is so good (speed, memory, functionality) it pays to start using it over `data.frame` at an early stage!

Comment: `data.table` is even more succinct if you set a key first: `setkey(dt, "b"); lapply(unique(dt$b), function(x) dt[x])`