# Store a single dataframe in environment from function in R

Tags: r, function, frame

Thank you in advance for your help!

I made a function in R that returns a dataframe, say `DF_Name` which have 4 columns, say `harder`,`better`,`faster`,`stronger`, and I just want to store this *single* dataframe in the Global Environment.

Here´s an *extremely simplified* version of the function:

```
daft_funct<-function()
{
  DF_Name <- read.csv("D:/SomeFolder/DF_Data.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  return(DF_Name) # I want to fix this line here
}
```

And these are my unsuccessfully attemps to store it on `.GlobalEnv`:

1. Without any knowledge:

   ```
   return(DF_Name) # Just shows on screen
   ```
2. Attempt to see the whole dataframe, shows but doesn´t store:

   ```
   View(DF_Name) # Shows on RStudio panel
   ```
3. Looking for help in StackOverflow and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704212/return-a-dataframe-from-a-function-and-store-it-in-the-workspace). 
   However it stores every single column of the data frame **as separated values**:

   ```
   list2env(DF_name,.GlobalEnv)
   # Check if worked
   >ls()
   "better"    "faster"    "harder"    "stronger"
   ```
4. Looking again for help in StackOverflow and found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414836/list-elements-to-dataframes-in-r). Which stores every single column of `DF_Name` again, but this time **as separated data frames**:

   ```
   list2env(lapply(DF_Name, as.data.frame),.GlobalEnv)
   # Check if worked
   >ls()
   "better"    "faster"    "harder"    "stronger"
   ```

Trying to merge the dataframes from 4th attempt into a single one inside the function leads to the main problem again.

*P.S.*: I have intentionally omitted `daft_funct` from `ls()`output.

Comment: The proper way to do it is not to put it in the global environment, but to have the user assign it. The user should just do `foo <- daft_funct()` and then they will have the data frame as an object named `foo` in the global environment.

Comment: As Gregor mentioned assigning to the global environment from within a function is not good practice but if you must then this will assign data frame `DF_name` to a data frame named `X` in the global environment. `assign("X", DF_name, .GlobalEnv)` . Note the dot in `.GlobalEnv` .

Comment: If you must bypass this, it is possible using `assign` or `<<-`, but this is frowned upon - generally R users expect functions will *not* modify the global environment internally. Your function may overwrite an existing object. If the user attempts to use your function like any normal R function (`foo <- daft_funct()`) they may be surprised and confused to have `foo` be useless. If the user doesn't know to look for an object with the name `DF_NAME` in their global environment, they will just think your function is broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Assign multiple objects to `.GlobalEnv` from within a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9726705/903061). The solution for multiple objects can clearly be simplified to a single object.

Comment: How didn´t I figure it could be that simple. Thank you @Gregor, there´s nothing wrong on `da_funk<-daft_funct()`. I'll be on shame forever.